# what is difference between return module or 'this'?

Tags: javascript

**hi!**
what is difference between **return** module or `this`?

return module and get instance is difference when i return `this`?

what is difference between `const obj` and  `this.obj` in this case?

```js
let module = function (value) {

    const obj = {};
// or
    this.obj = {};


    this.title = function (value) {
        this.obj.title = value
        return this;
    }
// or
    module.title = function (value) {
        obj.title = value
        return module;
    }

    return module;
    // or
    return this;
}
```

Comment: `module` is the function. `this` would be some object that's unlikely to be the function. [it's hard to say what, since it's determined at call time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429)

Comment: Using the `const` example `module.obj` will be undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `return module` vs `return this`, `module` is the function and `this` the object. That means that if you try to call the module, you will always get the function again and can end up doing calls like `module("")("")("")` and always get the same result. While if you only do it with `return this` you will get the object after calling the function `module("")` and then will be able to access all of the values from the object
2. When you are doing `this.title` you are modifying the object, meaning that if you removed the `module.title = ...` part you will never be able to access title if you return the module instead of `this`
3. And finally `const obj` is creating the variable inside the function, which means you can access it inside the function and can't use it outside, while `this.obj` is creating it as a property for the object, so if you get the object by doing `module("")` you can access the property `obj` like `module("").obj`

Also, you can always play with the variables to see how it works, if it isn't clear, you can copy this snippet and modify it.

```js
let module1 = function(value) {
  const obj = {}; // can only use it inside the function
  this.obj = {}; // property of the object

  this.title = function(value) { // you're modifying the object you're inside
    this.obj.title = value
    return this; // this is different from the outside this
  }
  module1.title = function(value) { // you're modifying the variable module and not the object it returns
    obj.title = value
    return module1;
  }

  return module1;
}

console.log(module1("").obj)
console.log(module1("").title)
console.log(module1("")(""))

let module = function(value) {
  const obj = {}; // can only use it inside the function
  this.obj = {}; // property of the object

  this.title = function(value) { // you're modifying the object you're inside
    this.obj.title = value
    return this; // this is different from the outside this
  }
  module.title = function(value) { // you're modifying the variable module and not the object it returns
    obj.title = value
    return module;
  }

  // return module;
  return this;
}

console.log(module("").obj)
console.log(module("").title)
console.log(module("")(""))
```